# What is the purpose of .enumerated() and .map() in this code?

Tags: swift, dictionary, enumerate

I'm working a tutorial from https://www.raywenderlich.com/921-cocoa-bindings-on-macos. I'm wondering what the .enumerated() and .map() functions are operating on in this section:

@IBAction func searchClicked(_ sender: Any) {

```
  guard let resultsNumber = Int(numberResultsComboBox.stringValue)
    else {
      return
  }
  iTunesRequestManager.getSearchResults(searchTextField.stringValue, results: resultsNumber, langString: "en_us") { (results, error) in
    let itunesResults = results.map {
      return Result(dictionary: $0)
    }

      .enumerated()
      .map({ (index, element) -> Result in
        element.rank = index + 1
        return element
      })

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.searchResultsController.content = itunesResults
      print(self.searchResultsController.content!)
    }
  }

}
```

I can usually figure out most things eventually in Swift but I'm stumped here and the explanatory text isn't clear to me either. I hope someone can help me understand this part of the tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked up the API documentations for enumerator aor map?

Comment: Yes I have, but in the documentation examples shown, what is being operated on is defined clearly (for me) such as:

for (n, c) in "Swift".enumerated() {
    print("\(n): '\(c)'")

and:

let cast = ["Vivien", "Marlon", "Kim", "Karl"]
let lowercaseNames = cast.map { $0.lowercased() }
}

Comment: `cast` is just an `Array<String>` (a.k.a. `[String]`). But so is `lowercaseNames` (the result of a call to `map`. There's no difference between values made via literals (e.g. `cast`), and those made via calls to functions (e.g. `lowercaseNames`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Map is used for modifications. At this point you are basically initialising an object of `Result` by giving `results` array as a param to it:

```
results.map {
   return Result(dictionary: $0)
}
```

`$0` means the first input. In a following case, `$0` is equal to `param`(we just gave it a name):

```
results.map { param in
   return Result(dictionary: param)
}
```

2. `.enumerated()` returns each element of an array with its index number. Without it you would have only the element like this:

```
 .map({ (element) -> Result in
        // you don't have `index` value inside the closure anymore
        // element.rank = index + 1
        return element
 })
```

Note that the `element` in the closure above is the same `Result(dictionary: $0)` object that you created in a previous `map` function.

3. At the end, you are making and modification by assigning elements index number increased by 1 to the element's `rank` property, and returning it:

```
 .map({ (index, element) -> Result in
        // element.rank = index + 1
        return element
 })
```

Note that the value we get after the 3rd step, including all modification is assigned to `let itunesResults`.

Comment: Thank you. This is complex but you've helped me understand it better.

Comment: Great to hear that! Please, mark it as answer if it helped you :) @JamesH

Comment: I did. I'm somewhat of a newbie here so I appreciate your thoughtful answer. Don't understand the downvotes for my question though without some clue as to what I could have done differently. I did quite a bit of research before coming here

Comment: Also I just tried a similar sequence of calls in a playground on two arrays of strings. Apparently .enumerated() and .map() work on the last declared array, so in the tutorial the array (dictionary) they operated on was itunesResults. A lot of Swift's behavior is implied from context so I'll have to work through that. Thanks again, everything is so much clearer now.